# Example of Hausdorff non-second-countable space such that every infinite subset has a limit point

Tags: general-topology

> Give an example of a Hausdorff non-second-countable space such that every infinite subset has an limit point

The cofinite topology over $[0,1]$ don't work, because this space is not Hausdorff. Hints?

Answer (score 1):

Another candidate is $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal in the order topology. It's limit point compact, first countable, hereditarily normal and not second countable. Munkres calls it $W$ I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Any compact Hausdorff space will do, and you can apply [Tychonoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff's_theorem) to get non-second-countable examples. Take, for instance, $[0,1]^X$ where $X$ is a set of uncountable cardinality.

Comment: you don't have a simpler example, have you? This theorem is in the next chapter of the book I'm reading, so I am supposed not to use it

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=[0,1]^2$.

If $r\in [0,1]$ then $\langle r,0\rangle$ has a local base of sets $$\Big\{\big[((r-\epsilon,r)\cup (r,r+\epsilon))\times[0,1]\big]\cup \big[\{r\}\times [0,\epsilon)\big]:\epsilon>0\Big\}.$$

If $r\in [0,1]$ and $s>0$ then $\langle r,s\rangle$ has a local base of sets

$$\big\{\{r\}\times (s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon):\epsilon>0\big\}.$$

Of course, sets in those two collections may not actually be subsets of $X$.  But I'm assuming that everything is intersected with $X$.

As long as you know that $[0,1]$ is compact, you should be able to prove that $X$ is compact in the topology given.

And $X$ is Hausdorff.  And non-second countable (because it is not separable).

Interestingly, this space *is* first-countable.

Comment: What is $\langle r, 0 \rangle $?

Comment: the point $(r,0)$.  But I use parentheses for open intervals.

Comment: Why $X$ is not separable? If we let $S$ be the set of the points in $X$ with rational coordinates, why is not $\bar{S}=X $?

Comment: Because the sets $\{r\}\times (0,1)$, $r\in [0,1]$, are all open.  A dense subset of $X$ has to have a point from each of them.  But there is an uncountable collection of them, and they are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Think I got the point. The topology is not the subspace topology, but you define it this way. If $U_r$ is the collection that you defined for $r$, then you take in $X$ the topology generated by the collection $U=\bigcup_{r\in [0,1]}U_r$. Is this right?

Comment: I defined a basis by specifying a basis at each point.  The topology is generated by the *collection* of all of these basic open sets, not the union. You're correct that it is not the usual topology on $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: But, man, this is a union of *collections*

Comment: Ah, okay.  Assuming your set $U_r$ has all the basic sets at each $\langle r,s\rangle$.

Comment: Now I'll do the math and back again later if needed. Peace